# How to call another PHP script from a PHP script?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that has a runtime of 34 seconds. But it dies after 30 seconds. I guess my webhost a time limit of 30 seconds.

I am thinking of splitting the script into two parts say PHP-1 and PHP-2.

Can I call PHP-2 from PHP-1 and kill PHP-1?
Both scripts have to run in sequence, so calling both of them using cron is not possible. [ My host provides cron with interval 5 mins and does not allow to change the start time]

-Will this circumvent the time limit set by host?

Comment: What is it that you're doing that's taking so long? Maybe there's another way to do it, especially if the user has to wait the whole time…

Comment: it runs in background. It fetches some data from the web.

Comment: Have tried set_time_limit(). It's of no use :(

Comment: Why do you need such huge fetching? usual rss feed take no more than milliseconds to fetch

Comment: I am fetching number of diggs for a list of urls...

Comment: May be it would be better to have your own content instead of fetching one that belongs to simeone else?

Comment: we're not saying about moral of such action, we talked about technique. Maybe he/she want to research on such data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function, it helps in most cases.

Alternatively, on Linux/Unix, you can try running the script as a background process. PHP CLI can be used for this purpose, the scripts running via CLI have no time limit. You can use [exec/system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) or similar PHP functions to fireup the PHP CLI and have it run a PHP script in background, returning control to the script immediately. In most cases, a PHP script running via CLI behaves just like it would do in CGI environment except for few environment related differences, such as no time limit.

Here is one way to do it:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php script.php > /dev/null &");
      ^            ^          ^           ^
      |            |          |           |
      |            |          |           +-- run the specified process in background
      |            |          +-------------- redirect script output to nothing
      |            +------------------------- your time consuming script
      +-------------------------------------- path to PHP CLI (not PHP CGI)
```

More details at: [Running a Background Process in PHP](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-background-process-in-php.html)

Comment: How can I call it using a thrid party cron? I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Your web-host might provide a cron service. And there are third-part cron services as well. Which ever you want to use, simply specify the url of your script (http://www.mydomain.com/cronjobs/myscript.php) there. There is a linux/unix utility called "wget" (http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html) which can grab the specified URL. wget or any utility that fetches a url can be used inside the cron job.

Comment: I believe you will always failed when using third party cron services. Because, it's still calling your http server which is still applied to 30 seconds limit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Answer (score 0):

Running it as CLI will automatically eliminate time limit. You can use cron for that as described by Salman A.
I have script that run for every 30 minutes. It does like this:

```
<?php
$timeLimit = 1740; //29 mins 
$startTime = time();

do 
{
   $dhandle = opendir("/some/dir/to/process");
   while ( (false !== ($file = readdir($dhandle))) ) {
      //do process.
   }
   sleep(30);
} while (!IsShouldStop($startTime, $timeLimit));



function IsShouldStop($startTime, $timeLimit)
{
   $now = time();
   $min = intval(date("i"));
   if ( ($now > $startTime + $timeLimit) && ($min >= 29 || $min >= 59) )
   {
      echo "STOPPING...<br />\n";
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}

?>
```

Why I did that? because I've read somewhere that PHP is very bad at garbage collection. Therefore I kill it every 30 mins.
It's not that robust. But, given the constraint of shared hosting. This is my best approach.
You can use that as template.

Comment: if ( ($now > $startTime + $timeLimit) && ($min >= 29 || $min >= 59) )
What is the part after && for?

Comment: it's to check if it's beyond 29 minutes also to safecheck so my script running only one at a time.