# How can I run another PHP script using PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call another PHP script from a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490373/how-to-call-another-php-script-from-a-php-script)

I want to run all the PHP scripts in a directory using PHP. Here's what I have:

```
foreach(glob('*.php') as $file)
  // Run $file
```

Comment: It's very well possible this is a very wrong solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). You could do something like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php ' . $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming a POSIX system

```
exec("nohup php $file >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: assuming a POSIX system of course.

Comment: always have to assume a lot of things, no one writes there questions with all the details.

Comment: It wasn't a critique of the answer. Merely letting anyone reading the answer know.

Comment: ye like right now im trying to determine how to do exactly this on a windows local server... no idea. nohup not an option it seems.