# php page run another script in background process not working

Tags: php, exec

I've read this [How can I run another PHP script using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438861/how-can-i-run-another-php-script-using-php) and some other sources.

so i have 2 files. testexec.php and testfile.php, the purpose of the testfile.php is to insert some query into table. the result running testexec.php is a success but no data inserted. i try accessing testfile.php directly and the data is inserted.

in testexec.php:

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    $pathFile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/textfile.php";
    $cmd = "usr/bin/php " . $pathFile;
    exec( $cmd , $output, $return);

    if(!$return) {
        echo "Fail";
    } else {
        echo "Success" . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

in testfile.php

```
<?php
    include("database.php");
    $myDB = new Database();

    $dateTime = new DateTime();
    $query = "INSERT INTO marking (description) VALUES ('Test Exec');";
    $result = $myDB->insertMysqli($query);
    if($result) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think that's because you use relative path here "usr/bin/php"
Try to use absolute - "/usr/bin/php"

Comment: Definitely. And a general remark: a "background script" always should log its activity somewhere. Preferably in a separate log file. And another thing: Most likely you would have been able to spot the cause if the issue yourself by taking a look into your http servers error log file...

Comment: try change the path to "/usr/bin/php". page return success but the data is not inserted. thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: i found solution to the problem. just wrong name file in $pathFile. should be testfile not textfile. :D the logfile really help arkascha. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the lines

```
$cmd = "usr/bin/php " . $pathFile;
```

By

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php " . $pathFile;
```

And

```
include("database.php");
```

By

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) ."/database.php");
```